# Explain how to obtain a field with $125$ elements using polynomials by using concrete example provided by a polynomial

Tags: field-theory, modules

I have this problem and don't know how to solve it. Any one can help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Furthermore, I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Take $\mathbb{F}_5[x] / (p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$.

One example of an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ is $x^3 + x + 1$. We can check this by evaluating that $x^3 + x + 1$ has no roots.

$\mathbb{F}_5 [x]$ is a PID since $\mathbb{F}_5$ is a field. Since $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, $\mathbb{F}_5[x] / (p(x))$ is a field.

Comment: A quadratic polynomial with degree $3$?

Comment: Sorry bad mistake.

Comment: This is the canonical answer for constructing finite fields of a given order.